# Change idVendor and idProduct of embedded USB device

Tags: linux, driver, kernel-module

Can I change those values on my Embedded device or do I need to recompile the Gadget Serial Driver?

Comment: I think the serial number should be in device which is being read by the driver. So i don't think its gonna help. But its worth a try if driver for that device have some module to perform the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass vendor and product id as module parameter. Something like below:

```
        insmod module.ko vendor="vendorid" product="productid"
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Helped a lot! How can I pass those parameters at boot time?

Comment: If you're using GRUB, you can edit the grub menu at the time of booting by pressing 'e' or you can modify the grub menuentry and explicitly pass the insmod command with your choosen "vendorid" and "productid". If you're using anything other than, I can't tell. I don't have experience with other bootloader. :-/

Comment: Just found it! I have to edit /etc/modules with the parameters. But I have to put a hex value. Can't I pass a string of my own choice?

Comment: Yes, product/vendorid are like - 0x1212. They should be in this (hex) format. Vendor/product id can't be on string format.

Comment: So what if I am a Vendor without a hex value? Can I somehow put my own Information there? or are the values matched on the host machine and?

Comment: Every vendor has unique vendorid and their product has a unique productid. Well, I'm not sure you're trying to achieve, but your info can't be put on driver by means of module param. You might've consider modifying the module you're using. Values aren't match inside driver/module code. But, yes there's some sanity checking whether users passes string or hex, to make sure that. The main intent behind {product,vendor}id passing is to make compatible drivers work.

Comment: For ex. newly developed device might not have a driver, but if it's compatible with generic driver, deviceid/productid could be passed as param while loading that generic driver and can make new driver work.

Comment: Thanks fpr the info! I just want my device to give my company's name when connected to a host.